# Using gulp and gulp-rename to output multiple stylus theme files

Tags: gulp, stylus, gulp-rename

I'm trying to set up a theme system for my project, what I have currently takes a theme file in stylus like `theme\default.theme.styl` that only includes variables storing colors and applies it to whatever other component style files we have included (e.g. `button.styl`).  The idea is that I can have more than one theme file, say `blue.theme.styl` and `red.theme.styl` and gulp will output two separate css files based on the component styling.  So I'd get `button.blue.styl` and `button.red.styl` as two separate files.

We want to be able to tell gulp which themes to compile through the CLI, so I set up the gulp task to take a build option of 'theme', and I'm using gulp-rename to add the theme name to the output files.  But, I can't get gulp to output multiple theme files if I give it more than one theme option.

```
TaskManager.createTask
  name: 'css'
  description: 'Build the component CSS files'
  options: buildOptions.concat
    name: 'theme'
    type: 'Array'
    description: 'themes to compile'
    default: 'default'
    supported: ['default', 'blue', 'red']
  hide: true
  fn: ->
    themeName = TaskManager.getArg('theme')
    DEST = 'dest'
    nib = require 'nib'
    stream = gulp.src ["src/**/*.styl", "!src/theme/*", "!src/global/*"]
      .pipe(plugins.plumber(errorHandler: TaskManager.error))
      .pipe(plugins.stylus
        use: [
          nib()
        ]
        include: [
          'src/util'
          'src/global'
          'src/theme'
        ]
        import: themeName.map (val) -> "#{val}.theme"
      )
      .pipe(rename (path) ->
        path.extname = ".#{themeName}.css"
        undefined
      )
      .pipe(plugins.filelog 'css')
      .pipe(gulp.dest 'dest')
```

This works as expected if I give it only one option at build so that `gulp --theme='blue'` will output `button.blue.css` with the appropriate theme styling.  But if I give it more than one option like `gulp --theme='blue,red'` I get files named `button.blue,red.css` that have whichever theme's file variables were included last as the colors that were applied.

Makes sense from what I understand of gulp and gulp-rename, but I want to be able to split the pipe at this point to get two different files.  I don't want to actually copy the files into a new directory, and solutions that manually create multiple streams to concatenate are not a satisfactory since I might only have one theme or there might be twelve, and I don't want to have to edit the build file to add new themes.  So how can I get multiple files compiled separately out of one stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it works to just return an array of streams:

```
TaskManager.createTask
  name: 'css'
  description: 'Build the component CSS files'
  options: buildOptions.concat
    name: 'theme'
    type: 'Array'
    description: 'themes to compile'
    default: 'default'
    supported: ['default', 'blue', 'red']
  hide: true
  fn: ->
    themes = TaskManager.getArg('theme')
    DEST = 'dest/components'
    nib = require 'nib'

    stream = []

    createTask = (themeName) ->
      return gulp.src ["src/**/*.styl", "!src/theme/*", "!src/global/*"]
        .pipe(plugins.plumber(errorHandler: TaskManager.error))
        .pipe(plugins.stylus
          use: [
            nib()
          ]
          include: [
            'src/util'
            'src/global'
            'src/theme'
          ]
          import: "#{themeName}.theme"
        )
        .pipe(rename (path) ->
          path.extname = ".#{themeName}.css"
          undefined
        )
        .pipe(plugins.filelog 'css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest 'dest')

    themes.map (name) ->
      task = createTask name
      stream.push task

    return stream
```